# MYSQL UPDATE data from a SELECT subquery for all row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update

I have a table "schLoc" like this

```
--------------------------------
| id | importo | iva  | totale |
--------------------------------
| 1  | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
| 2  | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
| 3  | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
| 4  | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
| 5  | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
| .. | NULL    | NULL | NULL   |
--------------------------------
```

and another table like this "schLocDett" like this where schLoc.id=schLocDett.id

```
---------------------------------------------
| idDoc | importo | iva  | totale | merce   |
---------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1.00    | 0.20 | 1.20   | fattLoc |
| 1     | 1.50    | 0.30 | 1.80   | fattSrv |
| 2     | 2.25    | 0.45 | 2.70   | fattLoc |
| 2     | 3.10    | 0.62 | 3.72   | notcSrv |
| 2     | 7.20    | 1.44 | 8.64   | fattSrv |
| 3     | 8.35    | 1.67 | 10.02  | fattSrv |
| 3     | 3.10    | 0.62 | 3.72   | notcSrv |
| 3     | 2.25    | 0.45 | 2.70   | fattLoc |
| 3     | 2.25    | 0.45 | 2.70   | fattLoc |
| 4     | 3.10    | 0.62 | 3.72   | notcSrv |
| 4     | 7.20    | 1.44 | 8.64   | fattSrv |
| 4     | 8.35    | 1.67 | 10.02  | fattSrv |
| ...   | ....    | .... | .....  | ....... |
---------------------------------------------
```

I would like to have the sum of importo, iva, totale foreach idDoc and this select query work perfectly:

```
SELECT LOC.id, SUM(DETT.importo) as importo, SUM(DETT.iva) as iva, SUM(DETT.totale) as totale  
FROM schLoc as LOC, schLocDett as DETT 
WHERE LOC.id>0 AND LOC.id=DETT.idDoc AND (DETT.merce='fattLoc' OR DETT.merce='fattSrv')
GROUP BY idDoc
```

but in the same time I would like to update "schLoc" table... I try like this

```
UPDATE schLoc AS LOC 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM( importo ) AS totImporto, SUM( iva ) AS totIva, SUM( totale ) AS totTotale 
    FROM schLocDett 
   WHERE idDoc=LOC.id AND (merce='fattLoc' OR merce='fattSrv')
) AS DETT 
ON LOC.id=DETT.idDoc AND LOC.id>0
SET LOC.importo = DETT.totImporto, LOC.iva = DETT.totIva, LOC.totale = DETT.totTotale;
```

but don't work.

Any suggests are welcome

Comment: I\`m guessing maybe that the reference to the outer table doesnt work in the subquery(`idDoc=LOC.id` ).If so just add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have written the query this way:

```
UPDATE schLoc AS LOC 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(importo) AS totImporto,
           SUM(iva)     AS totIva,
           SUM(totale)  AS totTotale,
           idDoc 
    FROM schLocDett
    WHERE merce IN ('fattLoc', 'fattSrv')
    GROUP BY idDoc
) AS DETT
    ON LOC.id = DETT.idDoc AND LOC.id > 0
SET LOC.importo = DETT.totImporto,
    LOC.iva     = DETT.totIva,
    LOC.totale  = DETT.totTotale
```

As @Mihai mentioned, it looks like you were trying to join with a correlated subquery, which might not work.  And in any case, the clearer thing would be to do the entire aggregation over documents in a subquery, and then update join to that.

Comment: Added missing column in select list hope you don't mind

Comment: @Prdp I don't mind at all.  Rextester doesn't work for DML queries, and Fiddle is always broken -- not easy to test my code :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot... right I try to use Fiddle to explain my problem but is alway broken. Bye